# Geopandas spatial select

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have a loop that selects a group of points based on a field value, in my case a trackID. I then have polygons built by buffering the those points by x meters, dissolving it, and converting it into single parts. The output will either be 1 polygon or multiple polygons depending on how far apart the point clusters are. The purpose of this is to select distinct groups of points. When I loop through the buffers to select the points from the subset that fall within the polygon I get;

```
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names
```

When I print and inspect each dataframe at this stage they show as being geodataframes with a geometry column. When I export the buffers to a featureclass and view it in QGIS I can see the polygons represent buffers of the points and that there are points within the polygons to select.
Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
for TrackID in TrackIDList:
n=n+1 ## Loop counter
currentdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_df[geo_df['TrackID'] == (TrackID)]) ## From all TrackPoints select only those where TrackID = TrackID
bufferdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_df[geo_df['TrackID'] == (TrackID)]) ## Set the buffer Dataframe to the point dataframe for buffering
bufferdf['geometry'] = currentdf.geometry.buffer(m) ## Buffer in metres (m = 55560)
bufferdf = bufferdf.dissolve('TrackID') ## Dissolve the buffers by TrackID
bufferdf = bufferdf.explode() ## Multipart to Singlepart
bufferdf['gid'] = range(1, len(bufferdf) +1) ## Assign Unique ID to the buffer features
bufferList = bufferdf.gid.unique().tolist() ## Create a list of unique gid to iterate over
for gid in bufferList: ## Iterator for the buffers
    cbuffer = bufferdf[bufferdf['gid'] == (gid)] ## Isolates the buffer with the curent gid numebr
    trakpoints = currentdf[currentdf.geometry.within(cbuffer)] ## Collect the points in the buffer
    print(trakpoints) ## Print the track points captured in the buffer
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...\BuildTracks.py", line 43, in <module>
    trakpoints = currentdf[currentdf.geometry.within(cbuffer)]
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 458, in within
    return _binary_op("within", self, other)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 67, in _binary_op
    data, index = _delegate_binary_method(op, this, other, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 40, in _delegate_binary_method
    this, other = this.align(other.geometry)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4274, in align
    return super().align(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8559, in align
    return self._align_series(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8662, in _align_series
    join_index, lidx, ridx = self.index.join(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3446, in join
    return self._join_multi(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3548, in _join_multi
    raise ValueError("cannot join with no overlapping index names")
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: fwiw - have you checked out scipy's clustering algorithms? they're super speedy and pretty effective. see e.g. [`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html)

Comment: I did but I ran into issues. One was I couldn't get kmeans to find the optimum number of groups based on the subset. Most subsets don't need this grouping applied, I just have some erroneous track points that are actually two tracks but somehow got the same trackID. I am trying to find away to isolate the separate tracks based on some spatial relationship. The other issue is kmeans tries to find centroids for each group, but my groups are long and thin, since they represent tracks. Points at the end of long tracks get assigned to the wrong cluster.

Comment: The buffer approach keeps the points in a line because it is all based on the distance to neighboring points with a certain trackID. The 2 tracks might be 100km apart and they might be several hundred long so kmeans tries to group them clusters that contain the ends of both tracks, the middles, and their beginnings. Where as the buffers merged by TrackID and overlap produce long polygons that contain the points belonging to the track. Since I got all that working already I just need to figure out what is up with the within clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intersection of two geopandas GeoSeries gives warning "The indices of the two GeoSeries are different." and few matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185667/intersection-of-two-geopandas-geoseries-gives-warning-the-indices-of-the-two-ge)

Comment: I think you need sjoin not intersection

Comment: Fwiw please always include the full traceback - it’s hard to even tell which line is causing the error

Comment: If I do basically the same thing with test GeoDataFrames it works, I can even buffer the whole dataframe of points and perform a within and get all the points back as a subset. It stops working when I try and use subsets. I seen that solution but it is about joining, I'm not trying to join the data just select points within the polygons. The polygon is just their to define a spatial group and separate point clusters. I'm looking in using sklearn DBSCAN and silhouette from here https://realpython.com/k-means-clustering-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because of the indices. You need to reset indices first.

Try this:

```
trakpoints = currentdf[currentdf['geometry'].reset_index().within(cbuffer.reset_index())]
```

Comment: I actually took a completely different approach to the task but I added this line to some old code and got a new error; since the geometries looked good so this must have worked.