# Compare two geodataframes, use the within function to compare the geometry on both dataframe and create a bool columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, coordinates, geopandas

I have two Geodataframes. First GeoDataframe contains polygons columns, and the other one contains points (latitude and longitude). I want to do this to check whether the coordinates I was provided are inside the polygon of the city. Please click on the image below to see both dataframe.

[GDF_1 contains polygon/multi-polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEuzh.png)

[GDF_2 contains city points (coordinate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR5GE.png)

When the ID is in gdf_1.id and gdf_2.id equal to each then uses the within the function to see if the coordinate in gdf_2 is inside the polygon in the gdf_1. For example, the code below would result in True because the coordinate is within the polygon.

```
poly = gdf_1[gdf_1.id == '17085']['geometry'] 
p1 = gdf_2[gdf_2.id == '17085']['geometry']
p1.within(poly, align=False)
```

I've been having hard time to iterate both Dataframe and compare them to each other. Is there anyways for me to compare both Dataframe to each other?

Desired output: (This is just an example)

| id | gdf_2.geometry | bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17085 | POINT(19.82092 41.32791) | True |
| 4505 | POINT(153.02560 -2746738) | True |
| 18526 | POINT(145.12103 -37.85048) | True |
| 5049 | POINT(146.36182 -41.18134) | False |
| 4484 | POINT(150.84249 -33.80261) | False |

Comment: Same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72193017/3888719

Comment: Can’t you just set the index as ID and call `gdf1.within(gdf2, align=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105955/9870343) was answered some years ago. That solution matches points in a list to polygons in a series. I am copying a modified version of that solution which will work with two data frames.

In this code sample `polydf` is equivalent to your `GDF_1` and `pointdf` is equivalent to your `GDF_2`. The "any" column in the example output is equivalent to your "bool" column.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas

polydf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({
    "polygons": ["A","B"],
    "geometry":[Polygon([(5, 5), (5, 13), (13, 13), (13, 5)]),
                Polygon([(10, 10), (10, 15), (15, 15), (15, 10)])]
})

pointdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({
    "points": ["a","b","c"],
    "geometry":[Point(3, 3), Point(8, 8), Point(11, 11)]
})

pointdf = pointdf.assign(**{row["polygons"]:pointdf.within(row["geometry"]) for index, row in polydf.iterrows()})

pointdf["any"] = pointdf.any(axis=1,bool_only=True).values

print(pointdf.to_markdown())
```

Output:

|  | points | geometry | A | B | any |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | POINT (3 3) | False | False | False |
| 1 | b | POINT (8 8) | True | False | True |
| 2 | c | POINT (11 11) | True | True | True |

This solution iterates over a table row-by-row. [This practice is not optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9870343), so it's possible that a faster solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

The geopandas api docs on [`geopandas.GeoSeries.within`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.within.html) are really great and I recommend giving them a close read. If the two dataframes have an index which can be aligned, passing `align=True` to many of the spatial ops will tell geopandas to join on the index, acting essentially like a normal pandas join, while performing the spatial op (in this case, within) on each pair of geometries.

So I think the following should do exactly what you’re looking for:

```py
gdf1.set_index("id").within(
    gdf2.set_index("id"),
    align=True,
)
```

This will be significantly faster than iterating over all rows.